# Loss in precision of float data type with pandas read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading the following data from excel using pandas read_excel function. When I read the data, I lose the decimals and numbers are formatted as integers.

[image: excel data]

```
# Read gdp data
df_gdp = pd.read_excel("~/Data/gdp_per_capita.xlsx", dtype={'Inflows': float, 'USD': float}, sheet_name="Data")

date       Inflows  USD
1980-12-31   0      0
1981-12-31   0      0
1982-12-31   0      0
1983-12-31   0      0
```

I also attempted to read data as `float`, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Hmm, this is working as expected for me in my test... I made an excel file copy of what you have and the same read_excel(); it actually works for me even without the `dype` parameter. Maybe you have something going on in Excel where the numbers are stored in a bad/wrong format? I did try myself to save them as text in Excel, but even though pandas read it fine as a float to two decimal places...

Comment: Yes, it's a bit strange. I have read float data previously and it's been working alright. This specific file I am experiencing the issue.